# Analog for operator :: in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, asynchronous

I can't fully understand how you can convert the code
`futuresList.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList())`
from Java to Kotlin code

I have a list of CompletableFuture and I want to combine for `CompletableFuture.allOf`

P.S. `val futuresList : MutableList<CompletableFuture<String>>`

Comment: `futuresList.map(CompletableFuture<String>::join)`, or even just `futureList.map { it.join() }`? `CompletableFuture.allOf` gives you a `CompletableFuture<Void>`, so you cannot get a `List<String>` out of that.

Answer (score 1):

Your original code is almost a working one, you just need to specify the type parameter:

```kotlin
futuresList.stream().map(CompletableFuture<String>::join).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Honestly, I'm not sure why this is required and why Kotlin does not use type inference in such a case. Alternatively, we can do it like this:

```kotlin
futuresList.stream().map { it.join() }.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

I believe this approach is more common in Kotlin.

Also, I'm not sure why do you use stream here. It seems the same as mapping the list directly:

```kotlin
futuresList.map { it.join() }
```

Comment: Although lambdas might seem more common (I have no idea in the wild), JetBrains recommends preferring the `::` style when it's possible (since it typically self-documents more concisely than a lambda can), although when you have to type out generic types, I think it becomes unwieldy. It certainly is odd it can't infer types in this syntax like it does elsewhere. At least it accepts `<*>`.

Comment: FWIW, I almost always find the lambda form easier to read (and shorter) than the the function reference (`::`) form.

Comment: I think lambda’s sometimes easier to read for a one-off, but if you have a chain of functional operations, `::` self-documents the types at each step which is helpful for review or when making modifications.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the kotlint code, which shows how to achieve what you want ...

```
fun main() {
    var newList = listOf(1, 2).map(Adder.Companion::addOne)
    newList.forEach { println(it) }
    // Will print 2, 3

}

class Adder {

    companion object {
        fun addOne(x: Int): Int {
            return x + 1
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a [working example](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS41LjMxIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiZnVuIG1haW4oKSB7XG4gICAgdmFyIG5ld0xpc3QgPSBsaXN0T2YoMSwgMikubWFwKEFkZGVyLkNvbXBhbmlvbjo6YWRkT25lKVxuICAgIG5ld0xpc3QuZm9yRWFjaCB7IHByaW50bG4oaXQpIH1cbn1cblxuY2xhc3MgQWRkZXIge1xuXG4gICAgY29tcGFuaW9uIG9iamVjdCB7XG4gICAgICAgIGZ1biBhZGRPbmUoeDogSW50KTogSW50IHtcbiAgICAgICAgICAgIHJldHVybiB4ICsgMVxuICAgICAgICB9XG4gICAgfVxufSJ9).